# unhandled promise rejection in nodejs

Tags: node.js

new to mongoDB and NodeJs. I am not sure why I keep getting unhandled promise rejection for the following code.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


router.get("/users",  (req, res) => {

  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("TestDB");
    dbo.collection("users").find({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result.Name);

      res.json(result);    

      db.close();
    });
  });


});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this example

```
const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)
    callback(docs);
  });
}
```

it will help you with your problem.

also check the documentation for examples:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/quick-start/quick-start/

what i would do with your code is this:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("TestDB");
  users = await dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray()    
  res.json({result:users});    
  db.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, as per official documentation use  callback inside toArray method.
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/quick-start/quick-start/

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


router.get("/users",  (req, res) => {

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("TestDB");
  dbo.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.Name);

    res.json(result);    

    db.close();
  });
});


});
```

Comment: so the only thing i was missing was the .toArray(function(err, result) part ?

Comment: Yes worked for me when I tried. If it works for you then upvote this, if not then leave a comment. I will again check.